# Why are there no files in a folder I specified to map volume in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minecraft

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine  
  
ENV VERSION="1.0.961"  
ENV URL="https://www.tekxit.lol/downloads/tekxit3.14/${VERSION}TekxitPiServer.zip"  
ENV MEM="4G"  
  
RUN apk add unzip  
RUN apk add wget  
  
RUN wget -O /tmp/tekkit.zip ${URL}  
RUN unzip /tmp/tekkit.zip -d /app/  
  
RUN mv /app/* /app/tekxit  
RUN chmod +x /app/tekxit/ServerLinux.sh  
  
EXPOSE 25565  
  
WORKDIR /app/tekxit  
RUN sed -i 's/Xmx4G/Xmx${MEM}/g' ServerLinux.sh  
RUN sed -i 's/Xms4G/Xms${MEM}/g' ServerLinux.sh  
  
CMD /app/tekxit/ServerLinux.sh
```

and following docker-compose.yml in one folder

```
version: '3'  
services:  
  tekxit:  
    build:  
      context: .  
    environment:  
      - VERSION:"1.0.961"  
      - MEM:"4G"  
    ports:  
      - 25565:25565  
    volumes:  
      - "./minecraft_data:/app/tekxit"  
    restart: unless-stopped  
  
volumes:  
  minecraft_data:
```

But when I do `sudo docker compose up`, I get an error `/bin/sh: /app/tekxit/ServerLinux.sh: not found` and there are absolutely no files in ./minecraft_data

When I don't try to map the volume to a folder inside the folder with docker-compose.yml, the container starts successfully

Comment: The `volumes:` block is hiding everything in the image.  `volumes:` always replaces the image content with the host content (which could be nothing); it does not make the image content visible on the host.  I'd recommend deleting that block from the Compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Use volumes on root indent of `docker-compose.yml` files only for named volume. For bind mount it is not required

Deleting these lines should solve the problem

```yaml
volumes:  
  minecraft_data:
```

Or try using full path directory

```yaml
version: '3'  
services:  
  tekxit:  
    build:  
      context: .  
    environment:  
      - VERSION:"1.0.961"  
      - MEM:"4G"  
    ports:  
      - 25565:25565  
    volumes:  
      - "D:/<path>/minecraft_data:/app/tekxit"  
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but that sadly did not help. It just creates an empty folder minecraft_data with no files in it :(

Comment: Does the container run successfully as expected? The files should be visible once your program make a write to disk.

Comment: It runs fine when I have the named volume in docker-compose.yml, but doesn't when I remove it. It errors out with `/bin/sh: /app/tekxit/ServerLinux.sh: not found`